# Calculating group average and assigning it to sub-group using Pandas groupby

Tags: pandas

I have a DataFrame with the populations of each city. I want to calculate the average population in each state using the populations from each city within that state.

Here's a sample of the data:

```
State     City         Population     State Ave
CA        San Diego    10000          ??
CA        Palo Alto    8000           ??
CA        Marin        5000           ??
SC        Columbia     4000           ??
SC        Charleston   3000           ??
SC        Greenville   4000           ??
```

I can retrieve the averages with:

```
data = pd.read_csv(/Downloads/test.csv')

grouped = data.group_by("State")

for k, group in grouped:
  print grouped.mean()

State       Population
CA          7666.66666667
SC          3666.66666667
```

But how do I assign the state average to each city?

Note: I tried to simplify a big problem with this smaller example and the data above, which is obviously not real.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `transform` and place the result in `df['Avg']`

```
In [216]: df['Avg'] = df.groupby('State')['Population'].transform('mean')

In [217]: df
Out[217]:
  State        City  Population          Avg
0    CA    SanDiego       10000  7666.666667
1    CA    PaloAlto        8000  7666.666667
2    CA       Marin        5000  7666.666667
3    SC    Columbia        4000  3666.666667
4    SC  Charleston        3000  3666.666667
5    SC  Greenville        4000  3666.666667
```

Answer (score 1):

mean = df.groupby('State')['Population'].mean()

df['mean'] = df.name.apply(mean.get_value)